# Convert DOCX footnotes into HTML or plain text?

Tags: html, docx, footnote

I have a Drupal installation and a bunch of DOCX files.  Like--several years of Sunday sermons?  I don't want to preserve 99% of the formatting, but they have footnotes.  I don't particularly care HOW the footnotes appear when it's added as Drupal content, just as long as they do actually appear.  I have found some DOCX-to-HTML converters but they all include a lot of formatting stuff and no option to disable that I can find.  Like, LibreOffice saving as HTML keeps all kinds of fonts and stuff and turns everything into CSS.  Saving as text in LibreOffice seems to retain the footnote numbers but loses their content.

Retaining stuff like bold/italics would be fine, but I don't want the margins, fonts, etc, because the Drupal site has its own styling.  It's just the silly footnotes I can't lose.

Alternatively, I guess a tool to strip out all the extra tags/styles might also work, but I'm not sure if such a thing exists.

Thanks!

Comment: are you mass-uploading html files or are you using a wysiwyg editor to add posts using drupal? If you are using an editor, some of them have a special "paste from word" feature (CkEditor for example) which also has (can be configured to have) a "remove formatting" checkbox to strip all the docx tags

Comment: This did indeed work!  We didn't have it installed before but that was easy enough, and it does import much more sanely than anything else exports.